# Do I need to add authorization headers manually in server actions if I have set them in middleware in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, middleware, next.js13

I am developing a Nextjs application, and I think I have some misunderstanding about the middleware's and how they works in Nextjs. I ask my question with a simple example:

suppose I have a simple middleware like this which add an authorization to headers for every single request:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
     const { cookies } = request;
     const token = cookies.get('access')?.value ?? null;
     request.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
}
export const config = { matcher: ['/:path*'] };
```

then in some component I have a button than upon click it runs a server action like this to fetch some data from an external django server.

```
import { getAds } from '@actions'.
import React from 'react';

const SomeComponent = () => {

  const fetchHandler = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await getAds(); // this is a server action
      console.log(res);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error happened', error);
    }
  }
  return <button onClick={fetchHandler}>Click to fetch ads</button>;
};

export default SomeComponent;
```

and following is the getAds:

```
export async function getAds(): Promise<ServerAdResponse<AdSerializer>> {
  const res = await fetch(`External django server address/ads`, {
    cache: 'no-store',
    headers: {
         authorization: `Bearer ${cookies().get('access')?.value}`, // Do I need this line
    },
  });
  const result = await res.json();
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }
  return result;
}
```

My problem is that when if I don't add the authorization header to fetch request in getAds server action, then django server complains about lack of credentials. I expect when I set authorization for every request then it shouldn't need to add it again in getAds function.